# Fixed header stays on top of wrapper

Tags: css, fixed

I'm trying to build a Wordpress site with a fixed header. So far so good. The header is ok, but the wrapper is the problem now. When I give the wrapper a margin-top: 100px the header wil go down 100px and header will stay above the wrapper (See image).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/18sOL.jpg
 . The transparent white is the header and it stays above the wrapper.

Code link:
http://jsfiddle.net/b1u83a7z/`enter code here`
 .Here you can see that the header is on top of the wrapper the wrapper should have a margin-top of 100px.

Comment: Try using `padding-top` on the wrapper instead of `margin-top`

Comment: Tried it, but the idea is that de wrapper is 100px below the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add header styles the `top` property to define at what position should be placed:

```
#top {
    top:0;   <-- Added
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    position:fixed;
    z-index:500;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1u83a7z/3/)